# How do I get an Epson SX235W printer working?

Tags: 10.04, printing

I have just installed Ubuntu on my laptop. But have a problem getting my Epson SX235W to work. I have installed the printer after finding the driver software, However when I try to print a document the printer just spits out sheet after sheet of blank paper until I switch the printer off. Please help.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

Try to go into your printer settings ( System Setting > Printer ), unplug your printer and delete the printer. After, plug your printer back and go into your printer settings again to see if there's your printer. If not, add it with the button and follow the instruction. If you can see your printer in the printer settings, try to print the ubuntu test page ( System setting > Printer > right click printer > properties > print test page)
If it doesn't work, try to look on epson's website.